# Ruby On Rails 3...Build query in pieces

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to build a query up in stages?

Example:

Lets say I have a search form with username, last name, active any of which could be blank/filled in.

There query should be OR'ed together based on the fields that are filled in:

SELECT * FROM table WHERE username = 'xyz' or last_name = 'abc' OR active = 'xyz'

BUT it could result in only 2 fields being queried... I need to somehow figure out how to or a query without doing something silly like string building.

Comment: RoR is lazy, queries won't be executed until needed

Comment: So on your search page, if I search for Username "John" and last name "Johnson", you want to return all users with either username as "John" OR last name as "Johnson"?

Comment: Yes, it is an or for all

Comment: If you are querying like this a lot you might consider indexing with Sphinx or the likes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in Rails 3:

```
ut = User.arel_table
User.where(ut[:username].eq('xyz').or(ut[:last_name].eq('xyz')).\
  or(ut[:active].eq('xyz')))
```

Which produces:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ((("users"."username" = 'xyz' 
  OR "users"."last_name" = 'xyz') OR "users"."active" = 'xyz'))
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're on Rails 3, you could use arel's chaining to AND these together.

```
@users = User.scoped
@users = @users.where(:username => params[:username]) unless params[:username].blank?
@users = @users.where(:last_name => params[:last_name]) unless params[:last_name].blank?
```

However, arel doesn't support OR conditions (yet) without doing string building.

Comment: Wouldn't these `AND` the conditions together, though?

Comment: So is string building the only way to go? That seems crazy

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way in Rails3 , without needing to use Arel would be do it like:

options = {}
options.merge({ :username => params[:username] }) unless params[:username].blank?
options.merge({ :last_name => params[:last_name] }) unless params[:last_name].blank?

@users = User.where(options)

There can be some really clever way to construct that options hash directly out of params depending on how you are exposing the attributes to the form.

Only limitation of the above approach with our Arel would be that you will be able to use operators other than equals (like not in or like).

If you want to really exploit all possible combinations take a look at [Squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) or if you want to go a step further and want the entire search build for you look at MetaSearch or MetaWhere

Watch the Railscast by Ryan Bates
http://railscasts.com/episodes/251-metawhere-metasearch